# replace all but - ,+, and . 

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a donation webapp, and I need to format a string the will leave minuses (-), pluses (+), and decimals (.).  I want people to be able to format their dollar amounts how they want, but leave the numbers and decimals as is.

I currently have the following code:
`var raised = $('#raised').val().replace(/\D/g,'');`

Any help? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Let me explain a little more about why this is an easy/quick way to validate the input.

This is going to be something that administration is going to use one time only, with only one person in charge.  It's not going to be something where multiple users input to submit actual money.  I agree that this could be much better planned, but this is more of a rush job.  In fact, showing you what I have done is going to be the quickest way to show you: http://www.cirkut.net/sub/batterydonate-pureCSS/

This is going to be projected during an event/auction so people kind of have an idea of how much money has been donated.

The person in charge of typing in donations is competent enough to type valid inputs, so I was putting together what I could as quickly as possible (the entire thing needs to be done by noon tomorrow).

But anyways I found what I needed.  Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Just curious (and so I can see better how this would need to be approached) but... where would the `+`/`-`come into play?

Comment: That is a bad way to validate input.  You should produce an error if a user puts in invalid data.  You should not try and guess valid data from invalid input.  In any case, what you are asking for won't work.  It would allow users to input strings like "2.2+1.2-12.3".  There is no way to take input like "2.2.34" and determine the users intention.  The quest you should be asking: How should I validate currency inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do exactly what you're asking, you could use this regex:

```
var raised = $('#raised').val().replace(/[^-+.\d]/g,'');
```

But be advised, you'll still need to verify that the returned string is a valid number, because strings like `'---'` and `'+++'` will pass. This, perhaps, is not even something you want to do on the client-side.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this is a bad idea, but you greatly understated how bad an idea it is.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex:

```
.replace(/[^\d\-+\.]/g, '')
```

Since this doesn't guarantee you have a valid number and not something like `+-12.34.56--1`, You can then validate that you have a valid number with something like:

```
/^[-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: `[^\d.+-]` looks a little nicer. Other than that, +1.

Comment: You have correctly answered the question, but does not address the fact that solving the problem will lead to a broken application.

Comment: @mikerobi - Correct, even tho this is a valid answer to the question it does not address the fact that it is possible the poster was unaware this in and of itself could still cause problems as you can still have plenty of invalid strings.  I added a validation regex that can be helpful in determining the validity of the number.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression character class can be negated by adding a `^` symbol to the beginning.

In your case, this makes it fairly simple: you could add all the characters you want to keep in a character class and negate it.

```
var raised = $('#raised').val().replace(/[^\d\.\+\-]/g,'');
```

Hope that helps.